# mongoDB/mongoose: unique if not null

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I was wondering if there is way to force a unique collection entry **but only if entry is not null**.
e
Sample schema:

```
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    name  : {type: String, trim: true, index: true, required: true},
    email : {type: String, trim: true, index: true, unique: true}
});
```

'email' in this case is not required but if 'email' is saved I want to make sure that this entry is unique (on a database level).

Empty entries seem to get the value 'null' so every entry wih no email crashes with the 'unique' option (if there is a different user with no email).

Right now I'm solving it on an application level, but would love to save that db query.

thx

Answer (score 243, accepted):

As of MongoDB v1.8+ you can get the desired behavior of ensuring unique values but allowing multiple docs without the field by setting the `sparse` option to true when defining the index.  As in:

```
email : {type: String, trim: true, index: true, unique: true, sparse: true}
```

Or in the shell:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({email: 1}, {unique: true, sparse: true});
```

Note that a unique, sparse index still does not allow multiple docs with an `email` field with a *value* of `null`, only multiple docs *without* an `email` field.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/

Comment: Awesome! Definitely the best answer for newbs like me after 1.8! NOTE: Mongoose won't update your unique index to be sparse if you just add a sparse : true to your schema.  You have to drop and re-add the index. Dunno if that's expected or a bug.

Comment: "Note: if the index already exists on the db, it will not be replaced." - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: I don't think this answers the question correctly, as a few documents without a specific field are not the same as a few documents with a null value on that field (which cannot be indexed uniquely).

Comment: @kako-nawao That's true, it only works for docs without the `email` field, not where it's actually there has a value of `null`. See updated answer.

Comment: Doesn't work with missing fields. Maybe behavior was changed in later versions of mongodb. Answer should be updated.

Comment: @joniba Not sure what you mean, as the whole point of a sparse index is to only include documents with the referenced field.

Comment: I agree that makes perfect sense. Unfortunately it doesn't work. You can run samyak's example below and see for yourself.

Comment: @joniba Sure, because samyak's example doesn't use `sparse: true`. Add that and it works fine. Might be best to post  a new question with what you're seeing.

Comment: It worked only after deleting the existing collection and recreating.

Answer (score 93):

## tl;dr

Yes, it is possible to have multiple documents with a field set to `null` or not defined, while enforcing unique "actual" values.

**requirements**:

- MongoDB v3.2+.
- Knowing your concrete value type(s) in advance (e.g, always a `string` or `object` when not `null`).

If you're not interested in the details, feel free to skip to the `implementation` section.

## longer version

To supplement @Nolan's answer, starting with MongoDB v3.2 you can use a partial unique index with a filter expression.

The partial filter expression has limitations. It can only include the following:

> - equality expressions (i.e. field: value or using the `$eq` operator),
> - `$exists: true` expression,
> - `$gt`, `$gte`, `$lt`, `$lte` expressions,
> - `$type` expressions,
> - `$and` operator at the top-level only

This means that the trivial expression `{"yourField"{$ne: null}}` cannot be used.

However, assuming that your field **always uses the same type**, you can use a [`$type` expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type).

```
{ field: { $type: <BSON type number> | <String alias> } }
```

MongoDB v3.6 added support for specifying multiple possible types, which can be passed as an array:

```
{ field: { $type: [ <BSON type1> , <BSON type2>, ... ] } }
```

which means that it allows the value to be of any of a number of multiple types when not `null`.

Therefore, if we want to allow the `email` field in the example below to accept either `string` or, say, `binary data` values, an appropriate `$type` expression would be:

```
{email: {$type: ["string", "binData"]}}
```

## implementation

### mongoose

You can specify it in a mongoose schema:

```
const UsersSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, trim: true, index: true, required: true},
  email: {
    type: String, trim: true, index: {
      unique: true,
      partialFilterExpression: {email: {$type: "string"}}
    }
  }
});
```

or directly add it to the collection (which uses the native node.js driver):

```
User.collection.createIndex("email", {
  unique: true,
  partialFilterExpression: {
    "email": {
      $type: "string"
    }
  }
});
```

### native mongodb driver

using [`collection.createIndex`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#createIndexes)

```
db.collection('users').createIndex({
    "email": 1
  }, {
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: {
      "email": {
        $type: "string"
      }
    }
  },
  function (err, results) {
    // ...
  }
);
```

### mongodb shell

using [`db.collection.createIndex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/):

```
db.users.createIndex({
  "email": 1
}, {
  unique: true, 
  partialFilterExpression: {
    "email": {$type: "string"}
  }
})
```

This will allow inserting multiple records with a `null` email, or without an email field at all, but not with the same email string.

Comment: Awesome answer. You're a savior.

Comment: This answer did it for me too.

Comment: Most of the accepted answers for this question involve making sure you are not explicitly setting null values to your indexed keys. That they instead be passed undefined. I was doing that and still getting the error (while using `unique` and `sparse`). I updated my schema with this answer, dropped my existing index, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Voted for this one, because it provides the knowledge and the possible answers based on the most common scenarios one would end up on this SO answer in the first place.  Thanks for the detailed answer! :+1:

Answer (score 8):

Just a quick update to those researching this topic.

The selected answer will work, but you might want to consider using partial indexes instead.

> Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, MongoDB provides the
>   option to create partial indexes. Partial indexes offer a superset of
>   the functionality of sparse indexes. If you are using MongoDB 3.2 or
>   later, partial indexes should be preferred over sparse indexes.

More doco on partial indexes: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, only first document where "email" as field does not exist will get save successfully. Subsequent saves where "email" is not present will fail while giving error ( see code snippet below). For the reason look at MongoDB official documentation with respect to Unique Indexes and Missing Keys here at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UniqueIndexes.

```
  // NOTE: Code to executed in mongo console.

  db.things.ensureIndex({firstname: 1}, {unique: true});
  db.things.save({lastname: "Smith"});

  // Next operation will fail because of the unique index on firstname.
  db.things.save({lastname: "Jones"});
```

By definition unique index can only allow one value to be stored only once. If you consider null as one such value it can only be inserted once! You are correct in your approach by ensuring and validating it at application level. That is how it can be done.

You may also like to read this http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying+and+nulls