# Mongoose does not create text index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
entrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    size:    { type: Number },

    title:   {type: String, trim: true },
    content: { type: String, trim: true },

    tags:    { type: [String], trim: true, index: true },
    author:  { type: String, trim: true, index: true }
  });


entrySchema.index({ title: "text", content: "text" });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', entrySchema);
```

The problem is that mongoose does not create the text indexes. The indexes for tags and author are created correctly, though.

Am I using the `index()` function in a wrong way?

I don't get any errors in the `mongod` session. It logs successful index creation for the non-text indexes, but it seems as if mongoose never calls `ensureIndex` for the text indexes.

Comment: I think you can't create a compound index with two text indexes: "A compound text index cannot include any other special index types, such as multi-key or geospatial index fields" (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#text-index-compound)

Comment: @joao as I understood that is exactly the way to go, as described in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/

Comment: you are completely right.

Comment: See this answer for some info on how to debug this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452865/mongoose-not-creating-indexes/12453041#12453041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging as described in [Mongoose Not Creating Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452865/mongoose-not-creating-indexes/12453041#12453041) (thanks to @JohnyHK for the link) I saw that the actual problem was not the text index.

I was using the [mongoose-auto-increment](https://github.com/codetunnel/mongoose-auto-increment) plugin and that resulted in errors indexing the `_id` field.
The solution was to have autoIncrement not use the `_id` field but a separate field like this:

```
entrySchema.plugin autoIncrement.plugin, {
    model: 'Entry'
    startAt: 1000
    field: 'shortId'
}
```

I just did not thing about that because indexing worked fine without the text index. There seems to be some kind of incompatibility with the plugin and text indexes.