# Mongoose schema: 'unique' not being respected

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use Mongoose with this schema

```
var RestoSchema = new Schema({
    "qname"          : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    ...
});
```

The problem is that this still permits new entries to the database to be created with an existing `qname`. From what i can see below the index has been created, but without any demonstrable impact when I use the `.save` method. What am I misunderstanding?

```
> db.restos.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "af.restos",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "qname" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "af.restos",
        "name" : "qname_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getIndexes` output shows that the index on `qname` wasn't created as a unique index.  Mongoose doesn't alter an existing index, so you'll have to manually drop the index and then restart your app so that Mongoose can re-create it as unique.

In the shell:

```js
db.restos.dropIndex('qname_1')
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it does not create a new index when I restart the app. Even added `index:true` to the list of properties for `qname`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452865/mongoose-not-creating-indexes for some tips on debugging that.

Answer (score 0):

ByronC's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613425/mongoose-unique-index-not-working) seems to have solved it for me.  I even tried dropping the collection and recreating and it still didn't work until I used the node.js NPM plugin called "mongoose-unique-validator" which you can learn more about [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator).

That said, the weird thing is that my unique index worked up until a schema change that implemented the "[uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)" plugin which I use now for setting the _id value.  There may have been something else going on but it is working for me now so I'm moving on.