# Unique Fields in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to enforce uniqueness by field on a mongoose model, in an existing database.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  }
})
```

Then when I create a user with an email that is already assigned, it passes, and I have 2 users with the same email.

I have read all related SO answers > 2015 and all about `dropDups`, [which is deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#indexes).

I think I fixed this issue by manually running

```
db.users.createIndex({email:1}, {unique:true})
```

However this obviously becomes cumbersome both in development and in production, especially considering the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) state that the attribute takes care of it:

> unique: boolean, whether to define a unique index on this property.

Can someone provide a clear solution to enforcing uniqueness by field on a Mongoose model, considering an existing database and a fresh collection? Thanks

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966146/mongoose-schema-unique-not-being-respected

Comment: @JohnnyHK How is this a possible dupe? Are you suggesting that everytime you want to add a collection with unique fields you must manually call `db.collection.dropIndex('fieldName_1')` ? Doesn't answer my question at all

Comment: What often happens is that you don't realize that the collection already has a (non-unique) index on the field, so Mongoose doesn't add the unique index you've defined. What does `db.users.getIndexes()` show?

Comment: I dropped the collection to start fresh and created a new user. `db.users.getIndexes()` now shows `[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "testdb.users"
    }
]` @JohnnyHK

Comment: You may have `autoIndex` disabled in your environment. Try enabling it by adding a call to `UserSchema.set('autoIndex', true);` and trying it again.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Ok done, and what should I expect there to happen ?

Comment: It should automatically create the index for you. Docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes).

Comment: @JohnnyHK ok... But if autoIndex is set to false and unique is set to true on a field, shouldn't mongoose build the index for that field anyways? I'm not sure I'm following where we're trying to get with this

Answer (score 1):

Two user has been created before unique index has been created.So you can insert two users with same email.You can try code below, it make sure all index has been created:

```
UserModel.on('index', function(error) {
  const user1 = new UserModel({
    email: '3489'
  });

  const user2 = new UserModel({
    email: '3489'
  });
  user1.save(console.log);
  user2 .save(console.log);
});
```