# MongoDB only creates text search index with language_override option

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoDB version 3.2.9, I can only get a text index created if I supply the language_override option as below (this is in Mongoose):

```
schema.index({ foo: 'text', bar: 'text' }, { language_override: 'text' });
```

Without the `language_override` option, the index is never created.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Are u using any `mongo` lib like moongose

Comment: This syntax is not mongodb's syntax is it? What framework , if any, are you using?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452865/mongoose-not-creating-indexes/12453041#12453041) for info on how to debug this. Otherwise, I think you'll need to provide a [MCVE] so others can reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: The library is Mongoose