# Mongodb how to enforce a unique db reference id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongodb how to enforce a unique db reference id?

```
const LikeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    idOfPost: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post',
        required: true,
    },
    userWhoLiked: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
        unique: true // This is not working? Why?
    },
    date=:{
        default: Date.now,
        required: true,
        type: Date,
    },
```

How can I make sure that all `userWhoLiked` fields are unique?

Comment: If your "AutoIndex" is "off" you need to call https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes explicitly. If you have documents that violate uniqueness the index won't be created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose unique validation not working. Duplicate entries getting saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435708/mongoose-unique-validation-not-working-duplicate-entries-getting-saved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/), then in the case of an insert/update of a document with a duplicate `userWhoLiked` value you'll get duplicate key error thrown.

Comment: At what point do you call `db.myCollection.createIndex()` is it after you have created your first document? Is it before? I am finding the docs a bit hard to understand. Where in the code do I place the createIndex command?

Comment: You do it once , so you don't really need to incorporate it in your code. Just run it once

Comment: The reference you shared really helped me.