# Change in mongoose Schema does not reflect

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, schema

In my NodeJS project, I have created a mongoose schema which I changed midway through the project. More specifically, I added the `unique` parameter to a field.

However, this change does not seem to reflect as I am still able to create multiple documents with the same value for the parameter which I set as `unique`

How to fix this issue

Comment: There might be errors while creating the index. Possible because of existing documents don't meet the index constraints. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452865/mongoose-not-creating-indexes/51833357) on how to check for index creation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose enforces the unique constraint by creating an index in MongoDB with the unique option.

If you already have duplicates in the collection, that index creation will fail.

Note that you may have to call [syncIndexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes) to update the database with the new index.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your node server. Sometimes, changes to the Mongoose model might not take effect until you restart your Node.js application. This is especially true if you're using a development environment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).