# Mongoose document schema and validation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I Have a schema like so:

```
class Schemas

  constructor: ->
    @mongoose = require 'mongoose'
    @schema = @mongoose.Schema

    @EmployeeSchema = new @schema
      'firstname': { type: String, required: true }, 
      'lastname': { type: String, required: true }, 
      'email': { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }, validate: /\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b/ },
      'departmentId': { type: @schema.ObjectId, required: true }
      'enddate': String,
      'active': { type: Boolean, default: true } 

    @EmployeeSchemaModel = @mongoose.model 'employees', @EmployeeSchema

    @DepartmentSchema = new @schema
      'name': { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } }
      'employees' : [ @EmployeeSchema ]

    @DepartmentSchemaModel = @mongoose.model 'departments', @DepartmentSchema
```

So that my `employees` live in an array of `employee` documents inside a `department`

I have several `department` documents that have a number of `employee` documents stored in the `employees` array.

I then added a new `department` but it contained no `employees`. If I then attempt to add another `department` without `employees`, Mongoose produces a `Duplicate key error` for the `employee.email` field which is a required field. The `employee.email` field is required and unique, and it needs to be.

Is there anyway round this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you enable Mongoose debug logging with the coffeescript equivalent of `mongoose.set('debug', true);` you can see what's going on:

```
DEBUG: Mongoose: employees.ensureIndex({ email: 1 }) { safe: true, background: true, unique: true }      
DEBUG: Mongoose: departments.ensureIndex({ name: 1 }) { safe: true, background: true, unique: true }      
DEBUG: Mongoose: departments.ensureIndex({ 'employees.email': 1 }) { safe: true, background: true, unique: true }
```

By embedding the full `EmployeeSchema` in the `employees` array of `DepartmentSchema` (rather than just an `ObjectId` reference to it), you end up creating unique indexes on both `employees.email` and `department.employees.email`.

So when you create a new `department` without any employees you are 'using up' the undefined email case in the `department.employees.email` index as far a uniqueness.  So when you try and do that a second time that unique value is already taken and you get the `Duplicate key error`.

The best fix for this is probably to change `DepartmentSchema.employees` to an array of `ObjectId` references to employees instead of full objects.  Then the index stays in the `employees` collection where it belongs and you're not duplicating data and creating opportunities for inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks Johhny, I wasn't aware of the _debug_ command, that's handy to know for future debugging. Nor was I aware that Mongoose was creating 2 indexes (really when I only asked for one.) I knew I could create 2 different collections and have one _refer_ to the other by means of an `ObjectId`, but then I'm back to a relational model. Having used RDMS's for many years I wanted to use an embedded structure which appears to be a good fit for this model. As a compromise I suppose I could refer to an _email-address_ collection from within the embedded employee object and create a unique index that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these references:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#sparse-indexes

[mongoDB/mongoose: unique if not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955040/mongodb-mongoose-unique-if-not-null) (specifically JohnnyHK's answer)

The short of it is that since Mongo 1.8, you can define what is called a `sparse` index, which only kicks in the unique check if the value is not null.

In your case, you would want:

```
@EmployeeSchema = new @schema
  'firstname': { type: String, required: true }, 
  'lastname': { type: String, required: true }, 
  'email': { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true, sparse: true }, validate: /\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b/ },
  'departmentId': { type: @schema.ObjectId, required: true }
  'enddate': String,
  'active': { type: Boolean, default: true }
```

Notice the `sparse: true` added to your index on EmployeeSchema's email attribute.

https://gist.github.com/juanpaco/5124144

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can't create a **unique** index on an individual field of a sub-document. Although the `db.collection.ensureIndex` function in the Mongo shell appears to let you do that, it tests the sub-document **as a whole** for its uniqueness and not the individual field.

You can create an index on an individual field of a sub-document, you just can't make it **unique**.

Comment: You can create a unique index on a sub-document field, but the uniqueness is enforced across the entire collection and 'no value' is considered one of the unique values.  See my answer.