# Schema for User table with multi strategy sigup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

While working on one project faced with problem of storing user information for different passport strategies(local, facebook, twitter).
At the begining my `UserSchema` had such look:

```
    User = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        "email" : { type : String , lowercase: true , trim : true , unique : true } ,
        "providerId" : { type : String } ,
        "providerName" : { type : String } ,
        "hashedPassword" : { type : String } ,
        "salt" : { type : String } ,
        "strategy" : { type : String } ,
        "created" : { type : Date , default : new Date().valueOf() } ,
        "lastConnected" : { type : Date , default : new Date().valueOf() } ,
        "accessToken" : { type : String } , 
        "securityToken" : { type : String , default : "" } ,
        "roles" : [ { type : String } ]
    }
);
```

But unique email brings problem with emails because two users with twitter stategy will have null email and this leads to error.

I thought about not making email unique but this brings alot( from the first look ) of problems.
One the solutions I see is making different schemas for each strategy but this is very difficalt to maintain.

Is there some other way of solving this issue. What are the best practices?

P.S. I swear I googled but didn't find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to be able to say unique:true and specify allowNulls. This now seems possible, as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693138/1935918

Comment: For a sparse index, two `null` entries will still violate the uniqueness constraint. However, if you don't add the `email` property to the document when it's null (that is, *only* add it when it has a proper value), it will work.