# Mongoose, unique username but not required (Mongo)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't know if this is possible, searched docs but can't find an answer.

I have a scheme where users sign up with Facebook Id and it gives there full name and id.

Later on in the journey users can sign-up to the multiplayer part and choose a unique username defined as such:

```
//In >> var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema
multiplayer.username: {type: String, unique: true, required: false}
```

My question is, when I attempted this with new user it just spits out the error:

```
New user request: Superman, facebookid: 13131231222
{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: gameserver.users.$multiplayer.username_1  dup key: { : null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: gameserver.users.$multiplayer.username_1  dup key: { : null }',
```

I've tried using default but it doesn't work, and I cannot use random because it's unique and not resettable.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955040/mongodb-mongoose-unique-if-not-null

and it doesn't work, same error.

Comment: It's telling you you're trying to insert a username with value null and that you already have a username with value null.  Can you confirm that multiplayer.username of all users you're saving is not null?

Comment: Some are null and some have chosen.

Comment: Don't use an actual value of `null`, just leave `username` unset (or set to `undefined`).

Comment: I figured it out, Mongoose wasn't updating the scheme on the actual Mongo server. You have to update the scheme manually or drop and recreate.