# E11000 duplicate key error collection in a UNDEFINED value. How avoid this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm making a project with node, mongoose and express.

I have this schema in mongoose

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  local: {
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
      ....
    },
    password: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  google: {
    googleId: String,
    email: String
  },
  ....
};
```

Because i have two passport strategies (local for the classic email, password and google).

But when i create two accounts with different google accounts. The console shows me this error:

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: xxx.users index: local.email_1 dup key: { : null }
```

WHAT?? The "Unique" detect duplicated two undefined values?

So. How can i avoid this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955040/mongodb-mongoose-unique-if-not-null

Comment: Nope. unique: true, sparse: true don't worked (same MongoError).

Comment: Did you drop the existing index first?

Comment: Yes. I'm deleted all the collections with robomongo. Then i put this in my schema.

local: {
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
      sparse: true,
      ....
    },

And i have the same error with two accounts created with google:

{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: xxx.users index: local.email_1 dup key: { : null }

Comment: Sounds like you're passing an actual value of `null` for that field. Just omit the `local.email` field in your doc when it isn't used.

Comment: Is ommited. const user = new User({
        profile: {
          firstName: profile.name.givenName
        },
        google: {
          googleId: profile.id,
          email: profile.emails[0].value
        }
      });

So. Mongodb detect two undefined local.email values and throw the stupid error.

Comment: What's in the `....` for that field of the schema? You don't have `default: null` there do you?

Comment: ... is the rest of schema. default: null don't worked

Answer (score 0):

hello i just solved the error
all you got to do is to go to Robomongo and in your collections i think is users open it you will find indexex delete the one who gave you the error the it solved