# How to create UniqueIndex and nullable string field in doctrine 2?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In a collection I have a string field that can be null some times. But, If that field has a value, it should be unique.I have tried like this,

```
/** @ODM\Field(type="string", nullable=true) @ODM\UniqueIndex(order="asc") */
private $empId;
```

I am using mongodb 3.0 ,doctrine 2 ORM on Zend Framework 2

Anyone know something on how to do that or if it's possible ?

Comment: Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693138/1697459

Comment: @Wilt, yes!, I got a answer from above, need to use 'sparse' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mongodb `sparse` option, I can achieve above scenario.

```
/** @ODM\Field(type="string" ) @ODM\UniqueIndex(sparse=true) */
private $empId;
```

See more:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/indexes.html