# Why this partialFilterExpression is throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User schema like this, when a user registers I want to set the default value as null but also to be able to set this value as unique. I tried the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955040/mongodb-mongoose-unique-if-not-null/43804473)
I literally copied the same solution however I am still getting this error 
`MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: ppp-ng-dev.users.$mobile_1 dup key: { : null }`

My Schema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    mobile: {
            type: Number, 
        required: false,
        index: {
            unique: true,
            partialFilterExpression: {mobile: {$exists: true }}
        },
        default: null,
    },
})
```

Why am I receiving this error even when the syntax is correct? (aparently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there are multiple documents in the collection with the value `null` for the field `mobile`. This violates the uniqueness constraint of the specified index. As JohnnyHK noted in the ticket you linked:

> Note that a unique, sparse index still does not allow multiple docs with an email field with a value of null, only multiple docs without an email field.

In your specific case, the `partialFilterExpression` specifies to only index documents where the field `mobile` exists, which includes documents where the field is defined and explicitly defined as `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So is there a way to allow null values to be saved into `mobile` field while maintaining uniqueness of the field?

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now, but you might want to look into having the partialFilterExpression on `$type` instead of `$exists: true`. This would exclude null values and index only defined values. I'm not sure what underlying BSON type will be used for `Number` in Mongoose though, so you may want to look into that and possibly consider storing as a string instead.

Comment: I am getting the same errors, even when no documents have `mobile` explicitly set to null.