# Mongoose: Unique field if it's not null or an empty string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So, I have the following schema:

```
const Players = new mongoose.Schema({
    discordID: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: function () {
        return typeof this.discordID !== "string" && this.discordID !== null
    }
})
```

My point is to make `discordID` unique, but only if it's not `null` or `""`.

I heard about sparse, but it doesn't seem to work as I want it to. I get duplication errors every time I'm trying to insert 2+ documents with discordID set to `null` (I tried `sparse: true` and `index: {sparse: true, unique: true}`).

Is there something I can do? I want to keep this validation on the schema level if it's only possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sparse indexes work for documents that *omit* the key. The required `discordID` is included and set to `null` which is passed onto the data store.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value. The index skips over any document that is missing the indexed field.

Set fields to `undefined` in mongoose for them to be removed before save.

Comment: This answer is helpful, however, I'm looking for a way to insert fields with null value. I don't want to have missing fields in documents.

Comment: found a dupe with the answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804473/1318694)... [partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/)